# What is the best way to sort these types of strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting

I need to get all files present in a directory and sub directory and each file have date append to file name like **product_log_2016-11-17.txt**

For getting list of the files present in a directory I used

```
all_logs = Dir["#{Rails.root}/log/product_logs/**/*.txt"]
```

and it returns full path file like this(I have removed my system path from each entry:

```
[
  "/log/product_logs/new_2/product_log_2016-11-17.txt",
  "/log/product_logs/new_2/products_log_2016-11-03.txt",
  "/log/product_logs/new_1/products_log_2016-10-04.txt",
  "/log/product_logs/new_1/product_log_2016-11-17.txt",
  "/log/product_logs/new_1/products_log_2016-11-03.txt"
]
```

But I want to be sorted list by date like this:

```
[
  "/log/product_logs/new_2/product_log_2016-11-17.txt",
  "/log/product_logs/new_1/product_log_2016-11-17.txt",
  "/log/product_logs/new_2/products_log_2016-11-03.txt",
  "/log/product_logs/new_1/products_log_2016-11-03.txt",
  "/log/product_logs/new_1/products_log_2016-10-04.txt"
]
```

I have tried like this:

```
all_logs.sort{|a, b|b.split("/").last.split("_").last.split(".").first <=>a.split("/").last.split("_").last.split(".").first }
```

Which is working but not seems a good solution, can anyone let me know what will be the best way to sot this type of the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
▶ input.sort_by { |i| [i[/\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/], i[/\d+/]] }
#⇒ [
#    [0] "/log/product_logs/new_1/products_log_2016-10-04.txt",
#    [1] "/log/product_logs/new_1/products_log_2016-11-03.txt",
#    [2] "/log/product_logs/new_2/products_log_2016-11-03.txt",
#    [3] "/log/product_logs/new_1/product_log_2016-11-17.txt",
#    [4] "/log/product_logs/new_2/product_log_2016-11-17.txt"
# ]
```

Two advantages compared to the answers given:

- It sorts the same date by the `new_???` number, and
- `sort_by` is way faster, than `sort`.

To receive a descending sorting, just chain a call to `Enumerable#reverse` in the end.

Comment: a way better solution +1 , probably a `reverse` is just required!

Comment: @dp7 yes, thanks for the tip about `reverse`, updated.

Comment: It will be fails when date will be like this: 2016-8-03

Comment: @Thorin if month and day might be 1-digit, use `\d{1,2}` matcher, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
all_logs = [
  "/log/product_logs/new_2/product_log_2016-11-17.txt",
  "/log/product_logs/new_2/products_log_2016-11-03.txt",
  "/log/product_logs/new_1/products_log_2016-10-04.txt",
  "/log/product_logs/new_1/product_log_2016-11-17.txt",
  "/log/product_logs/new_1/products_log_2016-11-03.txt"
]

all_logs.sort { |a, b| b.split("/").last.to_date <=> a.split("/").last.to_date }
```

Comment: There are any way to get list of files in sorted at once, I mean do not need to sort after getting list ?

Comment: @Thorin I think you have to do the sort explicitly after fetching the names.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
# Returns:
# 
# [
#    ["/log/product_logs/new_2/product_log_2016-11-17.txt", "2016-11-17"],
#    ...
# ]
date_mapping = array.map { |s| [s, s.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/)[0]] }

# Sort arrays, and then get the first elements.
date_mapping.sort { |a, b| [b[1], a[0]] <=> [a[1], b[0]] }.map(&:first)
```

Note the difference between the following two lines:

```
date_mapping.sort { |a, b| [b[1], a[0]] <=> [a[1], b[0]] }
date_mapping.sort { |a, b| [b[1], b[0]] <=> [a[1], a[0]] }
```

The second elements of the array specify how strings that use the same date should be handled.

Comment: Seems a better solution, but i need only sort by date and also need to get only those files those matches with a pattern, can I get those files directly ?
like File.open(file_path, "rb").grep(/"id"=>123/)

Comment: See `Dir.glob`: https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob You can use patterns like this (not regex): `Dir.glob('*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]*')`